# Synchronized Thread Communication is Java - Using only Primitive Constructs

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm struggling to achieve the perfect communication between my Server and Client Thread Sub-classes (Simulation). I read many articles, But I think I'm not getting the basic concept of how to synchronize threads.

**Issue:** 
My Server is receiving the requests from all three clients and after shutting down, Clients are printing the reply they got from server. But Server should respond a Client first and then should get another request from other threads.
Your kind help will really be appreciated. Thanks

Below are the Classes which are involved: 
**Server.java**

```
public class Server extends Thread {
private boolean isRunning;
private final Map < String, List < String > > content;
private final Queue < Request > requestQueue;

public Server(String name) {
    super(name);

    isRunning = true;
    content = new HashMap < > ();
    generateContent();
    requestQueue = new LinkedList < > ();

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override public void run() {
            Runner.logf("Timer    : Server shutting down...%n");

            isRunning = false;

            timer.cancel();
        }
    };

    timer.schedule(timerTask, 10 * 1000);

    start();
}

public synchronized boolean acceptRequest(Request request) {
    if (isRunning) {
        try {
            Field privateClient = Request.class.getDeclaredField("client");
            privateClient.setAccessible(true);
            Client tClient = (Client) privateClient.get(request);

            requestQueue.add(request);
            Runner.logf("Server accepted Request : %s\n", request.toString());
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    return false;
}

@Override public void run() {

    synchronized(this) {

        if (requestQueue.size() == 0) {
            Runner.logf("Server   : Request queue is empty, waiting...\n");
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        while (requestQueue.size() != 0) {
            Runner.logf("Server   : Has just been notified, getting back to work...\n");
            Request temp = requestQueue.poll();

            try {
                Field privateClient = Request.class.getDeclaredField("client");
                privateClient.setAccessible(true);
                Client tClient = (Client) privateClient.get(temp);

                Field privateMethod = Request.class.getDeclaredField("method");
                privateMethod.setAccessible(true);
                String tMethod = (String) privateMethod.get(temp);

                Field privateUri = Request.class.getDeclaredField("uri");
                privateUri.setAccessible(true);
                String tUri = (String) privateUri.get(temp);

                Field privateParameter = Request.class.getDeclaredField("parameter");
                privateParameter.setAccessible(true);
                String tParameter = (String) privateParameter.get(temp);

                List < String > tContent = content.get(tUri);

                if (tContent == null && tUri.compareTo("Index") != 0) {
                    tUri = "404";
                }


                if (tMethod.compareTo("GET") == 0) {
                    if (tUri.compareTo("Index") == 0) {
                        tContent = getKeys();
                        tUri = "Document";
                    }

                    Reply tRep = new Reply(tUri, tContent);
                    tClient.acceptReply(tRep);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

}

private void generateContent() {
    String key;
    List < String > value;

    key = "A";
    value = new ArrayList < > ();
    value.add("A1");
    value.add("A2");
    content.put(key, value);
    key = "B";
    value = new ArrayList < > ();
    value.add("B1");
    value.add("B2");
    content.put(key, value);
    key = "C";
    value = new ArrayList < > ();
    value.add("C1");
    value.add("C2");
    content.put(key, value);
    key = "D";
    value = new ArrayList < > ();
    value.add("D1");
    value.add("D2");
    content.put(key, value);
}

private List < String > getKeys() {
    List < String > keys = new LinkedList < String > ();
    for (String k: content.keySet()) {
        keys.add(k);
    }
    return keys;
}
}
```

**Client.java**

```
public class Client extends Thread {

private final Server server;
private final int periodOfRequests;
private final Random random;
private boolean firstRun;

public Client(String name, double frequencyOfRequests, Server server) {
    super(name);
    firstRun = true;
    this.server = server;
    this.periodOfRequests = (int)(1000.0 / frequencyOfRequests);
    this.random = new Random();

    start();
}

public synchronized void acceptReply(Reply reply) throws Exception {
    Runner.logf("%s : Got Reply %s\n", this.getName(), reply.toString());
}

@Override public void run() {
    Request req = null;

    synchronized(server) {


        if (firstRun) {
            firstRun = false;
            Request firstReq = new Request(this, "GET", "Index", "NA");
            Runner.logf("%s : Sent Request %s \n", this.getName(), firstReq);
            server.acceptRequest(firstReq);
            server.notify();
        }

        do {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(periodOfRequests);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            req = new Request(this, "GET", "A", "NA");
            Runner.logf("%s : Sent Request %s\n", this.getName(), req);
            server.notify();
        } while (server.acceptRequest(req));

    }
}
}
```

**Runner.java**

```
public class Runner
{

  private static final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "HH:mm:ss.SSS " ) ;

  public static synchronized void logf ( String format , Object ... args )
  {
    System.out.print ( sdf.format( new Date() )) ;
    System.out.printf( format , args            ) ;
  }

  public static void main ( String[] args )
  {
    if ( args.length == 0 )  { args = new String [] { "1" , "2" , "0.5" } ; }

    Server server = new Server( "Server  " ) ;

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < args.length ; i++ )
    {
      String name      = String.format     ( "Client%02d" , i+1 ) ;
      double frequency = Double.parseDouble( args[i]            ) ;

      new Client( name , frequency , server ) ;
    }
  }
}
```

**Current Output:**

```
04:40:23.522 Server   : Request queue is empty, waiting...
04:40:23.522 Client01 : Sent Request [Client01:GET:Index:NA] 
04:40:23.522 Server accepted Request : [Client01:GET:Index:NA]
04:40:24.522 Client01 : Sent Request [Client01:GET:A:NA]
04:40:24.523 Server accepted Request : [Client01:GET:A:NA]
04:40:25.525 Client01 : Sent Request [Client01:GET:A:NA]
04:40:25.526 Server accepted Request : [Client01:GET:A:NA]......
```

**What i want to Achieve:**

```
07:12:18.688 Server   : Request queue is empty, waiting...
07:12:19.204 Client02 : Sent request [Client02:Get:Index:NA]
07:12:19.204 Server   : Has just been notified, getting back to work...
07:12:19.204 Server   : Request [Client02:Get:Index:NA] is VALID, handling...
07:12:19.204 Client02 : Got reply [Index:A,B,C,D]
07:12:19.204 Server   : Request queue is empty, waiting...
```

Comment: What's up with the formatting? I can't read this..

Comment: @shmosel I just updated the question with proper formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is to just put the entirety of your `Server`'s `run()` method inside a loop:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    synchronized (...) {
        while (isRunning) {
            //
            // (check the Queue...process requests)
            //
        }
    }
}
```

I'd assume you need to do the same thing for your `Client` class.

Right now the `Server` checks the queue once and then the `run` method returns and the thread dies.

Also:

- You shouldn't be using `synchronized`/`wait`/`notify`/etc. on an instance of `Thread`. `Thread` uses the monitor on itself for other stuff, like [`join`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join-long-int-):

  > This implementation uses a loop of `this.wait` calls conditioned on `this.isAlive`. As a thread terminates the `this.notifyAll` method is invoked. It is recommended that applications not use `wait`, `notify`, or `notifyAll` on `Thread` instances.

  Instead, make an object field like `private final Object monitor = new Object();` and then synchronize on that. Make a getter so your `Client` class can access it if you want, but they probably don't need access to it. You should probably just put the `monitor.notify();` inside the `acceptRequest` method.
- Why are you using reflection to access private fields on e.g. `Request`?? Just make a getter.

Comment: I followed your direction, and just with some patience my issue is resolved and now threads are communicating properly.

Comment: just a small problem, When server is already shutting down and logged it's status to console, All three clients send one more request and program doesn't terminate. Can you help ?